# \vec conflict between llncs.cls and MnSymbol

Tags: incompatibility

I would like to use MnSymbol alongside Springer's LNCS class file, `llncs.cls`, which can be found in this [zip file](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) and in many other places on the web.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get the dreaded `! LaTeX Error: Command`\vec' already defined.`

What's the cleanest, simplest way to undefine the `\vec` introduced by `llncs.cls` so that I can `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`?

Comment: put `\let\vec\relax` before the usepackage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class `llncs` redefines `\vec` unless the `orivec` option is used.

```
\documentclass[orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

Hello! $\vec{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Usual *caveat*: using `MnSymbol` without setting the main font to Minion is not really typographically sound, as `MnSymbol` changes *all* symbols to a style that's rather different from other fonts' style.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of this caveat. Is there another question or some examples you can point me to?

Comment: @Roly Check http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Comment: I have consulted that entry before. Looking at it again, I don't see any mention of Minion, though. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Roly That's a general problem with packages such as `MnSymbol`, `mathabx` or `newtx`: they change *all* symbols to a possibly incompatible style; if only one symbol that's missing is needed, it's better to load only that one, rather than the whole set.

Comment: Ah, good to have that concisely summarised. Thanks. (And Mn stands for Minion, presumably?)

Answer (score 2):

I just found this solution in an old project:

```
\let\oldvec\vec% Store \vec in \oldvec
\documentclass{llncs}
\let\vec\oldvec% Restore \vec from \oldvec
```

I guess this answers my own question, but maybe there's something less hacky.

Comment: Probably `\documentclass[orivec]{llncs}` is better.